Deriving the score of a diffusion model under DDIM
I am trying to understand how the linear relationship between the diffusion noise prediction model $\epsilon_\theta(x_t)$ which predicts noise added to a sample and the score function is derived $$\nabla_{x_t}\log p_\theta (x_t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha_t}}}\epsilon_\theta(x_t)$$ as stated in equation 11 of (Dhariwal and Nichol 2021)
Lilian Weng's blog writes that given a defined forward noising process $q(x_t\mid x_0)\sim N(\sqrt{\bar{\alpha_t}}x_0, (1-\bar{\alpha_t})I)$ we have
$\nabla_{x_t}\log q(x_t) = \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[\nabla_{x_t}q(x_t\mid x_0)\right]= \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\frac{\epsilon_\theta(x_t,t)}{\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha_t}}}\right]=-\frac{\epsilon_\theta(x_t,t)}{\sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha_t}}}$.
While this chain of equalities seemingly recovers the desired equation 11, I have trouble understanding the first equality, $\nabla_{x_t}\log q(x_t) = \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}[\nabla_{x_t}q(x_t|x_0)]$

I think there are a couple of typos in the formula presented therein. Rather, we have
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \log q(\mathbf{x}_t)
&= \frac{\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_q}q(\mathbf{x}_t)}{q(\mathbf{x}_t)} \\
&= \frac{\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \int q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0)q(\mathbf{x}_0) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_0}{q(\mathbf{x}_t)} \\
&= \int  \frac{\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0)}{q(\mathbf{x}_t)} \, q(\mathbf{x}_0) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_0 \\
&= \int [\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \log q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0) ] \frac{q(\mathbf{x}_t | \mathbf{x}_0)}{q(\mathbf{x}_t)}q(\mathbf{x}_0) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_0 \\
&= \int [\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \log q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0) ] q(\mathbf{x}_0 | \mathbf{x}_t) \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_0 \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0|\mathbf{x}_t)} [\nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \log q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0) ] . \tag{*}
\end{align*}
Since $q(\mathbf{x}_t | \mathbf{x}_0) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_t ; \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}\mathbf{x}_0 , (1 - \bar{\alpha}_t) \mathbf{I})$, it follows that
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{x}_t} \log q(\mathbf{x}_t |\mathbf{x}_0) = - \frac{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{1 - \bar{\alpha}_t}} $$
where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ is a standard gaussian noise, independent of $\mathbf{x}_0 \sim q(\mathbf{x}_0)$, satisfying the relation $\mathbf{x}_t = \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t}\mathbf{x}_0 + \sqrt{1 - \bar{\alpha}_t} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$. Then the expectation in $\text{(*)}$ is a form of Bayesian inference. Indeed, it tries to predict this noise $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, solely based on the current image $\mathbf{x}_t$. (Note that $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ and $\mathbf{x}_0 \sim q(\mathbf{x}_0|\mathbf{x}_t)$ are no longer independent.) Then the noise prediction,
$$ \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0|\mathbf{x}_t)} [\boldsymbol{\epsilon}], $$
can be approximated by a neural network:
$$ \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_0|\mathbf{x}_t)} [\boldsymbol{\epsilon}]
\approx \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_\theta(\mathbf{x}_t, t), $$
to reach the conclusion.

This is very clear, I really appreciate you breaking it down for me!
